# Last row and column number in MS Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have often wondered what could the **very last row number** (in MS Excel) be since I first learned using the software. Of course, there must be a limit to the number of rows available. Or do the rows go on **infinite**ly if need be? Also, how many columns are there? Are they infinite?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Cursor Down</kbd> and it will go to the last row. It depends on your version, all newer versions have 1048576 rows (=2^20)

Answer (score 2):

It can support up to a maximum of 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns.